# Django. Many forms have OneToOne to one specific model. Forms should always be saved with these relations. How to implement efficiently?

Tags: django

I have many models (`Customer`, `Seller`, `Product` etc.), each of them has a set of images (`Gallery`, `OneToOne` relationship). 
Also, some models (`Customer`, `Seller`, `Moderator`, `Administrator`) has `OneToOne` with `User` that is used for storing credentials.

I want to create and update these related models together.

Of course, simplest way is to use a class-based view and override `get`, `post` and `form_valid` methods. But there are many models having `Gallery` and `User` and I intend to follow DRY and code reuse principles and not to alter each view in same way.

Ideally, solution is sophisticated form (or form set) and using of standard class-based views without method overriding. Other option is different form and class-based view mixin.

I thought few hours about mixins but didn't came up with solution. Now I'm trying to do something with some kind of form sets.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the gallery is recommended to create an app only for that purpose.

On the case of the user the implementation Here's my recommendation:

1 - Create a base `User` class with all the core functionality your looking for.

2 - Extend the `User` class for all the other cases with the functionality your looking for.

Comment: Thanks for answer. In my project there are several apps, gallery app is one of them. There are views for asynchronous uploading and deleting, `Gallery` model. Of course, saving gallery and other model data separately on different pages is pretty simple, but it slightly differs from what I am looking for :-) I want to save all data at once.

Comment: Also, it is not clear for me how to store inherited models in database. I use MySQL which doesn't support table inheritance. I am still searching for more general solution for both users and galleries (and other models which many other models have one-to-one relation with).